# Undirected graph datasets with node attributes?

Tags: data-request, network-structure

I'm looking for datasets of undirected graphs/networks that have node attributes. I'm aware of http://snap.stanford.edu/data/ but I can't find an undirected network **with** attributes data. I hope you can help.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is short list of attributed networks I know:

- [DBLP co-author](http://liris.cnrs.fr/~mplantev/doku/doku.php?id=data_sets)
- [SocioPatterns](http://www.sociopatterns.org/datasets)

I'm new user restricted to two links...
You can also search for `KDD2012 tencent weibo` dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Pokec social network is something like facebook that is viral in Slovakia,
it contains friendship relationship and nodes attributes. You may find the link [HERE](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/soc-pokec.html).